# Can I set environment variables at runtime with App Engine Standard using Java 8 runtime

Tags: java, google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform

As for the official documentation (https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/java/config/appref), a Java application using App Engine Standard for Java 8 runtime should describe it's env in an `appengine-web.xml` located under `WEB-INF` folder.

The chances are high those variables vary from env to env, and I refuse to build env dedicated artifacts.

Can I set those env vars in an external file? If yes how?

Answer (score -1):

You can't include external file for environment variables definition.

For this, I duplicate the `appengine-web.xml` and I store it in separate subfolders `WEB-INF/dev/`, `WEB-INF/uat/`, `WEB-INF/prod/`

Then, I use Maven to copy the `appengine-web.xml` from the right subfolder according with the profile passed to the build `-P` param

Not very maintainable because you have to replicate the modification in all the `appengine-web.xml` files, but I don't find a better trade off for having separate value per environment.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/24651376)

Comment: @sziraqui, I update my answer with the answer to the question: No, what do you want to do is not possible. Then, I let my workaround for achieving the same goal without the best pattern which exists, but which works.